# Upgrade to 19.04 completed with 2 errors, now I can only boot to TTY which cannot open display

Tags: boot, upgrade, gui, tty

At the cleaning up step of my upgrade to 19.04 from 18.10, the following error was reported:

```
Could not install 'linux-image-4.18.0-16-generic'
installed linux-image-4.18.0-16-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Followed by:

```
Error during commit
A problem occurred during the clean-up. Please see the message below for more information. 
installArchives() failed
```

Following this, the next option was "Restart", which I did and then arrived at a TTY login prompt.  I have logged in to TTY and installed all available updates.  If I try to launch Nautilus from the TTY prompt it reports `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` with a Gtk warning `..cannot open display:`.

I tried Boot-Repair-Disk but this only succeeded in removing the nice purple GRUB boot menu, so now I have to boot via the GRUB command line.  Using a live USB, I compared the /boot folder with /boot on a good 19.04 machine and all files and subfolders appeared to match with the exception of an efi folder which was missing on the bad machine.  I copied the efi folder across from the good machine but this did not help.

Is there anything else I can do to save this system?

---

#### Update 21 Apr 2019:

I found and used the startx command which successfully launches a GUI from TTY, albeit with Adwaita, not the Yaru theme and icons.

GRUB is now fixed after I observed /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new and /etc/default/grub.d had been purged and not repopulated at some stage during or since the upgrade.  However it is still booting to TTY.

I got Yaru back by installing gnome-tweaks and selecting it with that, and after a few more reboots I am becoming more comfortable with the TTY login.  Ubuntu Dock is missing or not working but I will post that separately (although I am starting to like the "Fedora" look of the dock).

---

**Update:** After posting the above update I installed lightdm.  I am now booting directly into the GUI and no longer needing to log in via TTY and launch the GUI with the startx command.

Comment: OK so is your issue solved? Moreover 19.04 uses gdm3 as its default login screen but you can stick lightdm if you like it.